# JavaScript minification fails containing certain Regex

Tags: javascript, asp.net, regex, asp.net-mvc, bundling-and-minification

I can't minify a javascript file containing this working `Regex`:

```
isValid = function (str) {
    return !/[~`!#$%\^&*+=\-\[\]\\';,/{}|\\":<>\?]/g.test(str);
},
```

Error message:

```
/* Minification failed. Returning unminified contents.
(2128,43-44): run-time error JS1004: Expected ';': {
(2128,45-46): run-time error JS1195: Expected expression: |
(2128,46-47): run-time error JS1014: Invalid character: \
(2128,47-48): run-time error JS1014: Invalid character: \
(2128,48-70): run-time error JS1015: Unterminated string constant: 
                                     ":<>\?]/g.test(str);
(2129,6-7)  : run-time error JS1195: Expected expression: ,
(2128,17-43): run-time error JS5017: Syntax error in regular expression: 
                                     /[~`!#$%\^&*+=\-\[\]\\';,/ 
*/
```

Bundle Config:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundlesJs/custom").Include(
    "~/Scripts/Autogenerated/AntiHacking/antiHackingHelper.js"
));
BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;
```

How can this be solved? Is there a character that needs to be escaped or should I wrap the whole Regex?

Comment: Oh maybe I just have a bad escape. I think I needed `\`before `/` `[~`!#$%\^&*+=\-\[\]\\';,\/{}|\\":<>\?]`
I tryed it here: https://www.regex101.com/

Comment: Yeah that did it. I had copied the regex from a SO answer with many votes and I used the regex alot for a year ago. Next time I'll test the regex https://www.regex101.com/ before using it. 
https://www.regex101.com/ have easy-to-read error messages.

Comment: The point is that you actually can use ``/`` inside a character class *non-escaped* BUT not in all browsers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Acc. to [ES5 docs](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.10.1), the forward slash is NOT a special regex metacharacter.

JavaScript regex engine always allows an unescaped `/` in a `RegExp` constructor notation *and* you may use an unescaped `/` forward slash inside character classes even when written in a regex literal notation, try this  code (in Chrome, FF, and I have checked it in IE 11, too):

```js
console.log( '1//25///6'.match(/\w[/]+\w/g) );
console.log( '1//25///6'.match(RegExp("\\w/+\\w", "g")) );
```

However, **the best practice** is to ***escape the regex delimiters*** to avoid any issues like the one you have and keep the patterns consistent and unambiguous.